# How can I find this word is Substitutions: or Insertions python

Tags: python, string

For example, my word is "brain", we need to create function that check is it subsitutions and is it insertions.
For example, Substitutions can be:  train  grain  blain  bryin ... Insertions:  barain  bryain  ...

```
#I am not sure I did the right way or missing something. And any other way that faster?
#string0 is pattern

def subsitutions(string0, string1):
     sublist = []
    for i in range(len(string0)):
        sublist.append(string0[:i] + string0[i + 1:])
    for i in range(len(string1)):
        if string1[:i] + string1[i + 1:] in sublist:
            print("This word is subsitutions")
            break

def insertions(string0, string1):
    if len(string0)+1 == len(string1):
        for i in range(len(string1)):
            if string1[:i] + string1[i + 1:] == string0:
                print("This word is insertions")
                break
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  You seem to be asking several very general things.  Your posted code does not show *any* problem: it's two functions with nothing to call them.

Answer (score 1):

`set.difference` would easily do this for you:

```
>>> set('brian') - set('bryan')
{'i'}
>>> set('brian') - set('byrian')
set()
```

Here's a dirty example of this check:

```
def check_sub_or_ins(pattern, string):
    if set(pattern) - set(string):
        print("This word is subsitutions")
    else:
        print("This word is insertions")
```

You will need to check the length of each string though as just using `set` won't work for all strings

Comment: so you just compare len(pattern) == len(string) so what hapen if i compare the word "brain" with "abcde"

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
word = "brain"
word_length = len(word)

words_to_check = ["train", "grain", "blain", "bryin", "barain", "bryain"]

for word_to_check in words_to_check:
    boolean_list = [character in word for character in word_to_check]
    character_occurences = sum(boolean_list)
    if character_occurences == word_length - 1:
        print("{0} is substitution".format(word_to_check))
    elif character_occurences >= word_length - 1 and len(boolean_list) > word_length:
        print("{0} is insertion".format(word_to_check))
```